# How to find invariant points of a function and its inverse?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, inverse-function

Given a function $f(x) = \ln(x+1)$ and its inverse $f^{-1}(x) = e^x - 1$ , find the invariant points.

After equating the two $y$ values of a function, $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$, I get:

$e^x - 1 = \ln(x+1)$

I am unable to solve this equation since I don't know whether I should just express the $e$ value or if there is a more sophisticated approach?

Comment: There is one trivial solution. Then, you can graph it to get intuition. And study the difference, it's monotony, etc.

Comment: @LaurentDuval What would be the trivial solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saying $f(x) = f^{-1}(x)$ means that they intersect along the line $y=x$. We could equivalently ask for either

$$x = e^x-1$$

$$x = \ln(x+1)$$

Which both have solutions at $x=0$ by guessing. A little IVT magic proves that this is the only solution for either equation.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice way to think about it. It hasn't crossed my mind even though it's really the very definition of the inverse function. I just wonder whether my approach of equating the y values could be solved as such or if the method at play is just too complex?